# User specific software not getting registered in proper location in registry

Tags: windows, architecture, registry

Before asking my doubt let me put up my understanding regarding the registry locations which stores the details of installed software.
**For 32-bit System**
 1. 64-bit softwares cannot be installed
 2. Software location of 32-bit software
 ->For normal(system) software:

> HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\

->For user specific software:

> HKUsers\{User
>   sid}\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\

**For 64-bit System**
1.Software location of 64-bit software
->For normal(system) software:

> HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\

->For user specific software:

> HKUsers\{User
>   sid}\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\

2.Software location of 32-bit software
->For normal(system) software:

> HKLM\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\

->For user specific software:

> HKUsers\{User
>   sid}\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\

Please correct me if I made any mistake. Also, please provide me with any proper reference regarding this for future usage. If the above statements are proper, then I have my doubt as below.
I have a 64-bit system. When I try to install a 32-bit normal system software, its entry is getting registered in WOW6432Node as mentioned above. But, when I try to install an user specific 32-bit software, its entry is getting registered in the location

> HKUsers\{User
>   sid}\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\

Please explain me why is behavior happening. Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253(v=vs.85).aspx) HKLM/Software is **redirected** but HKCU/Software is **shared**

Comment: I'm sorry I am not quite understanding this. HKCU/ would not even be  necessary for me.

Comment: Current User is just an alias for USERS\{SID}. Anyway, according to MSDN the point is that for Local Machine you have a redirected entry (your assumption is right) but for USERS\{SID} you have a shared entry (then assumption is wrong but you observe expected results)

Comment: I went through the content and still couldn't understand the terms registry redirected, reflected and shared. Can you please brief about them in shirt and what is the reason for these functionalities?

Comment: To make it very short...redirected: you're redirected to read/write to another path (you may think about it as an alias); reflected: you read/write a synchronized copy; shared: you read/write the same key. Of course there are more _tricks_ (see MSDN) around them, this is really a imprecise explanation.